# assertion in java

Tags: java, assert

i have created an assertion line as below

```
String title = "A";
int year = 2009;
String director = "Zebra";
```

VideoObj a = new VideoObj(title, year, director);

```
Assert.assertFalse(a.equals(new VideoObj(title+"1", year,director)));
```

why does this fail??
the equal method is below.

```
public boolean equals(Object thatObject) {
    if (!(thatObject instanceof VideoObj))
        return false;
    VideoObj that = (VideoObj) thatObject;
    return ((_title.equals(that.title())) && (_director.equals(that.director())) && (_year == that.year()));
}
```

but the below statement

```
Assert.assertFalse(a.equals(new VideoObj(title, year, director + "1")));
```

does not fail?
can some one explain why the first assert statement fail and not the second?

Comment: Please show a short but *complete* program demonstrating your problem. In particular, that's a bizarre equality method.

Comment: Your `equals` method is very wrong.

Comment: this is what i got from my professor

Comment: Does the predicate still fail to deliver the expected result after correcting the change to `&&`? And why is the *year* not germane to equivalence?

Comment: it works now,
but y didn't it go through if it were a ||????

Answer (score 1):

You probably meant to use `&&` instead of `||` in:

```
    return ((_title.equals(that.title())) || (_director.equals(that.director())) || (_year == that.year()));
```

Otherwise you're checking that *any of* title, director or year are the same, not that *all of them* are.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't it rather be 
     ((_title.equals(that.title())) && (_director.equals(that.director())) && (_year == that.year()))

Two videos are equal if title AND year AND director is equal, not when only 1 of them is...